# Animation with white frame sometimes Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

Running an animation sequence with 28 frames, all CORRECTLY named, but when I run this animation, every now and then (it's not always in the same frames) a white square appears for a few milliseconds...

Here's the code:

```
    var birdAnim1Array = [SKTexture()]
    for i in 0..<28{
        birdAnim1Array.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Crossbar_bird1_separated-flight1_\(i).png"))
    }
```

And then it's called in this function:

```
func spawnOrNotFlyingNode(){
    let rand = arc4random() % 15

    if rand == 0 {
        //add flying node
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Crossbar_bird1_separated-flight1_0.png")

        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            flyingNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        flyingNode.setScale(ssscale*0.33)

        flyingNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX + 150, y: self.frame.size.height*0.9)
        // flyingNode.zPosition = 11
        flyingNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: flyingNode.size.width, height: flyingNode.size.height))
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = FlyingNodeCategory
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BallCategory
        flyingNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BallCategory
        self.addChild(flyingNode)

        flyingNode.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: -300, duration: 8.0))
        flyingNode.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: birdAnim1Array, timePerFrame: 0.02, resize: false, restore: false)))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 8.0) {
            if !self.hitFlying{
                self.flyingNode.removeFromParent()
            }
            self.hitFlying = false
        }

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
        self.spawnOrNotFlyingNode()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using imageNamed correctly, do not include the `.png` otherwise you lose your @2x @3x images, which may be the reason why you are getting distorted graphics

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to solve it... Still looks the same. Also, I only have sd quality images, no 2x and 3x yet

Comment: well that may be a problem as well,  the system would have to make them for you then, and that process could be broken.  I would make the 2X and 3X and see if you get the same results

Comment: Nope... same results... super weird

Comment: I have seen SpriteKit sometimes gets confused when it uses automatic node sizing. Try setting an explicit size for the node, e.g. `SKNode(texture: texture, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))`.

Comment: Fixed it! Problem was that the frames for the animations were different sizes, so I had to do resize: true... stupid mistake